# Get file from GCS without downloading it locally

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple Spring Boot microservice that takes care of uploading, retrieving and deleting images to/from Google Cloud Storage. I have the following code for the get request in my service:

```
public StorageObject getImage(String fileName) throws IOException {
    StorageObject object = storage.objects().get(bucketName, fileName).execute();
    File file = new File("./" + fileName);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

    storage.getRequestFactory()
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(object.getMediaLink()))
            .execute()
            .download(os);
    object.set("file", file);
    return object;
}
```

And this is my controller part:

```
@GetMapping("/get/image/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    try {
        String fileName = imageService.findImageById(id);
        StorageObject object = gcsService.getImage(fileName);

        byte[] res = Files.toByteArray((File) object.get("file"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .body(res);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("No such file or directory");
    }
}
```

It all works fine in terms of getting the image in the response, but my problem is that the images get downloaded at the root directory of the project too. Many images are going to be uploaded through this service so this is an issue. I only want to display the images in the response (as a byteArray), without having them download. I tried playing with the code but couldn't manage to get it to work as I want.

Comment: Display them how exactly?  Please edit the question to be more specific about the final result you have in mind.

Comment: Is this a question about 'In-memory java.io.File'? If so, then [this question might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595091/how-to-create-a-new-java-io-file-in-memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to instead [stream the download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-download-object-java), while skipping the `FileChannel` operation:

```
public static void streamObjectDownload(
    String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String targetFile
) {

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    try (ReadChannel reader = storage.reader(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName));
        
      FileChannel targetFileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(targetFile), StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {

          ByteStreams.copy(reader, targetFileChannel);
          System.out.println(
              "Downloaded object " + objectName
                  + " from bucket " + bucketName
                  + " to " + targetFile
                  + " using a ReadChannel.");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStacktrace()
    }
}
```

One can eg. obtain a `FileChannel` from a `RandomAccessFile`:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(Paths.get(targetFile), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
```

---

While the Spring framework similarly has a [`GoogleStorageResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/api/index.html?org/springframework/cloud/gcp/storage/GoogleStorageResource.html):

> `public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException`
> Returns the output stream for a Google Cloud Storage file.

Then convert from `OutputStream` to `byte[]` (this may be binary or ASCII data):

```
byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it work for you to create [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) in Cloud Storage to display your images? These URLs give access to storage bucket files for a limited time, and then expire, so you would rather not store temporary copies of the image locally as is suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614506/17544309).

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: I'm sorry I've had no time to look into this problem the past weeks. Thanks for your answer, I'll look into this option